# Change Start position of Quadrotor using moveit

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

```
             I am trying to use moveit package for planning path of my quadrotor. I have been able to publish goal points for the quadrotor to move, however, as moveit takes initial position from joint space, the start position is always fixed to [0,0,0,0,0,0,1]. I want to know if its possible to change the start position.
```

P.N. - Since this a quadrotor, there's no end effector and hence I cannot use this snippet to change the start position.

---

robot_state::RobotState start_state(*group.getCurrentState());
geometry_msgs::Pose start_pose2;
start_pose2.orientation.w = 1.0;
start_pose2.position.x = 0.55;
start_pose2.position.y = -0.05;
start_pose2.position.z = 0.8;
const robot_state::JointModelGroup *joint_model_group = start_state.getJointModelGroup(group.getName());
start_state.setFromIK(joint_model_group, start_pose2);
group.setStartState(start_state);

---

Thanks in advance
Poulastya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215189/change-start-position-of-quadrotor-using-moveit/) by [p_mukherjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/22619/p_mukherjee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to create a workaround for this problem. While running moveit demo.launch file, I found in rqt graph that, /move_group goal can both publish to and subscribe from the move group node. I created a publisher which publishes to /move_group/goal and a subscriber which subscribed to /move_group/display_planned_path. After that I used these waypoints to move the hector quadrotor using the hector quadrotor's controller.

P.N - the joint space won't be updated, so you won't be able to see the quadrotor move in rviz, but it works fine in gazebo

---

Originally posted by [p_mukherjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/22619/p_mukherjee/) with karma: 16 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0